# Update button in play store not work with my new update

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

I had uploaded an application using flutter, first version is `1.0.0+1` after two weeks, I upload a new version of the same application with this version `1.0.1+2`

I upload the new version and uploaded successfully **BUT** update button not shown up, I got an open button in the play store.

Everything is working fine with the app store.

**Note :** I changed the `VersionName` and `VersionCode` from `.yaml` file

**I did these :**

- I clear the play store cache.
- I spent about a day or more waiting to update play store servers.

Comment: Do you have this app on device?

Comment: Yes, I have this app on my device.

Comment: What do you wait for? You have this app on device with last version. Check update date on app's play store page.

Comment: I have this app with version ```1.0.0+1``` and last update on the store is ```1.0.1+2``` and open button showing on my device. I'm waiting for update button.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one reason for this. First, you can try to clear the Play Store cache with [these steps](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-202631/):

> From a Home screen, navigate: Apps > Settings > Apps.
>
> Note If unavailable, navigate: Apps > Settings > (Applications) Application manager.
>
> Note For Oreo OS, navigate: Apps icon > Settings > Apps & Notifications > App info.
>
> Tap Google Play Store.
>
> Tap Storage.
>
> Tap Clear Cache then tap Clear Data.
>
> Tap OK.

If it does not work, wait some time because the Play Store does not update immediately all servers around the world.

Comment: I cleaned the play store cache and nothing changed, maybe need to wait to update the servers. But I see last update is a new date and the button still open. I wanna ask if we think the servers need some time to update, What expected time for this update? Is it taking days?

Comment: I hope it is not taking days. We selected the availability of the app only for our country. After that, it becomes faster.